# How to get the tab of the observed HTTP request and load content on it

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Here is a code snippet that does what I need in a Firefox add-on. I need to intercept HTTP requests. The code changes the header of the request. But what I need is identify the tab where the request made in, and load script on it. I am working on an SDK add-on and have no choice to work on webextesnion. It is for local purposes not to be published.

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var httpRequestObserver =
{
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) 
  {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
      var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);
    }
  }
};
```